# How to pass numbers greater than 9007199254740991 to contracts?

Tags: web3js, bignumber

When I try to call function `check()` with a number greater than 9007199254740991 I get an error:

> Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed

```
contract C {
     function rateCheck(uint rate){
          if(rate % 10 finney != 0 || rate == 0){
             throw;
          }
     }
}
```

---

**Question:**
What's the best workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Summary

- 10 finney is equals to 0.01 ethers or 10000000000000000 wei. Refer to http://ether.fund/tool/converter.
- The native units in `geth`, solidity and the web3 interface is in wei.
- Floating point numbers are currently unsupported.
- Your code is trying to perform that following conditional check

  ```
  if (rate % 10000000000000000 != 0 || rate == 0)
  ```
- The condition will fail if rate = 999999999999999
- The condition will pass if rate = "999999999999999000000000000000000".
- You can also use `web3.toWei("999999999999999", "ether")`
- You will have to double quote your long numbers so the JavaScript interpreter treats it as a BigNumber. See [A note on big numbers in web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js) for further information.

---

### Details

Your issue is not with the large number.

Following is the code to test whether the large number is causing the problem:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Test {
    uint256 public rate;

    function setRate(uint256 _rate) {
        rate = _rate;
    }
}
```

Here is the Browser Solidity screen showing that your number will be accepted via the web browser commands:

[image]

And I tried interacting with the contract through the `geth console` command line:

```
> var testABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"rate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_rate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setRate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}];
undefined
> var testAddress="0x0016e39f81fb2968fd3cd1c9a0cefcfc4400322c";
undefined
> var testInterface = web3.eth.contract(testABI).at(testAddress);
undefined
> testInterface.setRate(999999999999999, {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000})
"0x6b337f89f71e4e6fd40675392804dedfb0038049e2c4f32cb13e088d94a1d352"
> testInterface.rate()
999999999999999
```

Following is the screenshot that demonstrates that the problem is likely to be around the `%` operator:

[image]

Following is the Browser Solidity screen showing that your function works correctly - provided you pass the right units. And because the number is large, I had to enclose it in double quotes so the JavaScript interpreter passes the number as a BigNumber.

[image]

Here is a check from the `geth console` command line:

```
> var testABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"rate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rateCheck","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}];
undefined
> var testAddress="0x2df61b421b5a6c42ab31a666634301047639355d";
undefined
> var testInterface = web3.eth.contract(testABI).at(testAddress);
undefined
> testInterface.rateCheck(9007199254740991, {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000})
"0xad9856272b9862df1b1a471b897b4ea1fe619174051a11fdf98516750bf7c5ed"
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xad9856272b9862df1b1a471b897b4ea1fe619174051a11fdf98516750bf7c5ed")
{
  blockHash: "0x2956aca46107b646611bf1b5c788ac08e60f7cd4c5672e4b319e39aaf43fb1c3",
  blockNumber: 17127,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 500000,
  from: "0x5ad21746717442a76089bde62720412f29aee414",
  gasUsed: 500000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x27a5aff06d0f622311982b12f33d15672cfc2d6627cf554c8f126c3e1e6f7431",
  to: "0x2df61b421b5a6c42ab31a666634301047639355d",
  transactionHash: "0xad9856272b9862df1b1a471b897b4ea1fe619174051a11fdf98516750bf7c5ed",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
// gasUsed == gas supplied - error was thrown
> testInterface.rateCheck(web3.toWei("9007199254740991", "ether"), {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000})
"0x93b8b8c2d78d465ef97024f3dd81267c6cf2f9ae7680f6e4d137a05341d0329e"
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x93b8b8c2d78d465ef97024f3dd81267c6cf2f9ae7680f6e4d137a05341d0329e")
{
  blockHash: "0x2e26507caa37e947d07e3e419ad67a7b11430200d7ec5da16e03c35bc9220d27",
  blockNumber: 17139,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 22450,
  from: "0x5ad21746717442a76089bde62720412f29aee414",
  gasUsed: 22450,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x52df9a3abec58e84fcf0b429fb008b011c7b17452f3908803d81cf2eb2f0fe8c",
  to: "0x2df61b421b5a6c42ab31a666634301047639355d",
  transactionHash: "0x93b8b8c2d78d465ef97024f3dd81267c6cf2f9ae7680f6e4d137a05341d0329e",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
// gasUsed != gas supplied - no error was thrown
```

Comment: hey, thank you! I messed up here a bit.  It's actually anything larger than 9007199254740991 that causes the problem. For example, 900719925474099**2** throws an error. Editing...